# Как растянуть блок на всю высоту страницы?

Tags: html, css, css3

Вопрос по `CSS`. Задача: есть высокий блок-контейнер, он по высоте не помещается на один экран (например, `div`, в котором много параграфов), надо задать фон этому блоку-контейнеру, чтобы он был закрашен полностью.

Нашел вот такое решение: задать всем блокам-родителям `height: 100%;`, а блоку-контейнеру задать `min-height: 100%;`. Вот пример:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
</div>
```

**Не понимаю, почему это работает**. Похоже на "шаманство". `min-height` задает минимальную высоту. Получается, что минимальная высота содержимого дива равна 100% высоты содержимого `div`. Посмотрел в devtools, выяснилось, что `div` может быть по высоте больше, чем `body` и `html`.

Comment: что собственно вам не понятно? как по другому сделать высоту блока на всю страницу?

Comment: мне не понятно, почему это работает. как связана минимальная высота с высотой на всю страницу?

Comment: высота родителя  - 100% страницы. минимальная высота вашего блока - 100% родителя -> 100% страницы. Можете задать блоку высоту в 100vh, результат будет тот же) про эти единицы измерения можете поискать информацию. ее полно)

Comment: правильно, а минимальная высота вашего блока - 100% боди - что и есть 100% страницы. Просто для этих целей используйте height: 100vh)

Comment: высота боди - 100% высоты хтмл, высота хтмл - 100% высоты вьюпорта. а вьюпорт - это область просмотра, а не вся страница

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Работу min-height: 100% можно понять на примере с установкой прилипающего футера. При этом есть стили:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body,
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
}
.footer {
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: -80px;
}
```

И разметка:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="content">

        <p>ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй ййй </p>
        <p>ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц ццц </p>
        <p>ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу ууу </p>
        <p>ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк ккк </p>
        <p>еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее еее </p>
    </div>

    <div class="footer"></div>

</div>
```

**При этом `min-height: 100%` работает ТАК:**

1. Если СОДЕРЖИМОГО МАЛО у блока `content`, то его высота МИНИМАЛЬНО равна 100%  высоты вьюпорта (`wrapper` - это 100% от высоты `body`, `body` - это 100% от высоты  `html`, а `html` - это 100% от высоты `viewport`). При этом у блока content есть нижний `paddind`-буфер отрицательный, а у блока блока `footer` есть отрицательный `margin`, который позволяет в случае, когда много содержимого, "наползти" на этот `padding`-буфер.
2. Если же содержимое НЕ ВЛЕЗАЕТ на экран (содержимого МНОГО в блоке `content`), то высота определяется содержимым - содержимое растягивает.

*Еще раз повторю, чтобы все запомнили - если содержимого мало, высота блока равна высоте вьюпорта (это и есть МИНИМАЛЬНОЕ значение высоты, то есть, меньше быть не может, а больше - пожалуйста, если сможешь растянуть содержимым), если много - высота блока БОЛЬШЕ высоты вьюпорта и определяется содержимым, которое на эту высоту и растягивает.*

Answer (score 5):

#### Почему это работает?

Потому что `div` просто переполняет (вылазит за границы) `body` и всё. Задавая `overflow: hidden;` для `body` мы увидим, что `div` просто обрезается (если высота экрана небольшая).

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
  <p>text text text text</p>
</div>
```

#### Как с этим быть?

Это задавание `height: 100%;` блокам всех уровней вложенности довольно неудобно. Задайте просто нужному вам блоку `min-height: 100vh;`, где vh — единицы высоты экрана. У `body` тогда будет по умолчанию `height: auto;` и `body` просто будет подстраиваться под содержимое.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. не понимаю, как связана минимальная высота с высотой на всю страницу

Comment: я знаю, что див переполняется. и что при задании overflow: hidden; это переполнение "обрезается". вопрос в том, как див по высоте оказался больше боди и хтмл

Comment: Да потому что `body` и `html`, когда им задают 100% занимают один экран. А `div` занимает **минимум** один экран, но может и больше (как в данном случае) при `min-height: 100%;`.

Comment: @Dimon Вам помог ответ на вопрос?

Comment: идею с 100vh подкинули

Comment: @Dimon А объяснение с высотой вам понятно?

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: stretch;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]